# How can you disable the "right click and save" function on videos?

Tags: mediaelement.js

How can you stop people from right click and saving your video? Is there a way to disable this?

Answer (score 2):

```
$('#divVideo').bind('contextmenu', function(e) {
return false;
});
```

You can disable the right click using this code. the divVideo will be the div container which contains the video player or something.